# How to redirect url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to redirect url using .htaccess from -

http://www.reservationnumbers.com/companydata.php?name=apple

to

http://www.reservationnumbers.com/apple

OR

http://www.reservationnumbers.com/companydata.php/apple

Comment: You want to write in address bar `http://www.reservationnumbers.com/companydata.php?name=apple` and call to `http://www.reservationnumbers.com/apple` ? Or vice versa ?

Comment: No I want  http://www.reservationnumbers.com/companydata.php?name=apple to redirect http://www.reservationnumbers.com/apple

Comment: I have tried RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ comapanydata.php?name=$1 [QSA] but it doesnt works

Answer (score 1):

To redirect `/companydata.php?name=apple` to `/apple` you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /companydata\.php\?name=apple [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /apple? [L,R]
```

If the name permameter is dyanamic, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /companydata\.php\?name=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /companydata.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Parameters are dynamic and now its redirects to 404

Comment: What url are you going to? this works if you enter **/companydata.php?name=apple** and redirects to **/apple** does the uri **/apple** exist?

Comment: @user1831355 if the answer solved your issue, please accept it by clicking the backtick sign.